Removing a stuck washing machine
A couple of months back my roommate decided to buy a washing machine. The designated space within our home's bathroom is extremely limited and can only fit the narrow washing machines that open from the top. Needless to say, he miscalculated the size and the washing machine did not fit.
Here is an image that describes the situation:
.
We managed to place it inside, by stacking it on top of a stool and the stool on top of a small cabinet, then pushing the stack inside and carefully removing the stool and the cabinet. It was a very difficult ordeal that required 4 people. We were hoping that the washing machine would be functional for as long as we lived there, as there are very few problems that a technician can fix within that crammed space.
Unsurprisingly, after a single month the washing machine broke. The rotating bin inside it seems to have come undone, and it doesn't seem like it can be fixed without removing it. By looking at the picture it should be apparent that we can't possibly lift it and remove it the same way it was placed in. I can't figure out a way to remove it and as such, I can't buy another washing machine to do my laundry.
If you have any ideas as to how I can tackle this problem they would be greatly appreciated :)

Hard to tell, but it appears that the limiting factor above may be a towel rack. Towel racks are usually (but not always) relatively easy to remove. If that can be done, a gradual lift (placing stool or cabinet or whatever underneath as you move up) and then pull out over the sink should be doable.

@manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact The towel rack (as well as the boiler which is not shown in the picture but is right above) did not pose too much of a problem when we put it in. However because its in a corner, we don't have the right balance to lift it like we did when it was placed. It's really a product of sheer stupidity on our part...

Have you considered removing the vanity so you can remove the washer and then reinstalling it?

@JACK This seems to be a legitimate option. I am hesitating a bit however, because we are renting the place and the landlady is pretty strict.

@crip659 Could you elaborate a bit?

Would breaking it apart and removing the pieces be an option as well? I am not sure where to start though, there don't seem to be any visible screws besides the one behind the panel

Regarding the landlady, if you protect the floor appropriately with cardboard, an engine hoist is going to be your best option, I believe. Good enough that @crip659 should turn his comment into an answer. The boiler may post a complication, although you should be able to lower the crane enough to squeeze in. Washing machine tops are secured with screws in the back, and the top slides forward to disengage dogs until it can be lifted. Repairing in place may be impossible, but if you plan to dispose of it, the removal of the top is the starting point.

Breaking it apart has problems because the drum shaft, gear box and motor are in the back and have some nuts and bolts that would be hard to get to from the front.

There are air-bag jacks. If the washer can be lifted enough to slide an air-bag underneath, it can be lifted enough to slide in supports, then the bag placed on supports...

wedge a pole at an angle braced against wall and floor. attach hand winch or pulley and rope the lift for stool etc.

An engine hoist might help to lift the washer high enough.  Should be able to rent one, but not expensive if you can find other uses.
Just a nice picture of a hoist.

Will want cargo straps to fit under the washer and up the sides.
Cardboard or old carpet to protect the walls/vanity.
heavy cardboard or wood sheets(plywood/OSB) to protect the floor.
Three or four people to help to finish lifting/moving the washer.

@DrMoishe references air bags, which would be a good addition to raise it up enough for the cargo straps to get under. I also searched for "mini engine hoist" to discover that there are abbreviated versions of the one listed.

@fred_dot_u   As I said it is just a nice picture.  The mini might not be available as a rental or maybe is.  The OP should be able to wiggle the washer enough to place it on the legs.  The washer should tilt enough for straps to go under or use fishing tape to help.

It is indeed a nice picture and also appeared in my search results. Along with those images, a winch appeared as well, but one would have difficulty securing a winch above the machine, if there's a boiler interfering.

IDK how you'd get the feet for that type of hoist under the washer...

@Huesmann   You tilt the washer back and then wiggle the washer on and legs under.  Does help to have a few friends around.

I'm not sure how this would get it high enough. The hoist head would need to be at around ceiling height to get the entirety of the appliance above the counter. Also, the legs need to be under everything, which isn't option here. This is one of those looks clever at first things that really won't work well at all.

@isherwood exactly—you'd need to customize the hoist so that the legs fit between the wall on the left and the cabinet on the right.  And the gap is widest only at the front, so you'd need to account for the taper in the width as you go further underneath the washing machine.

How?  There's no space for legs and the center of gravity must remain within the square (or possibly other shape) defined by the corners.  Even if you could somehow make legs at a 45 the washing machine will be right at the edge of the area that can be supported.  The only way I could imagine it working is if you had adjustable legs that could be pointed as desired and an ability to add a counterweight

@LorenPechtel   That is only one design and only shown as an example of an engine hoist.  The OP and you would need to google for a design that would work.  Most washers/appliances can be tilted back enough to fit legs/stuff under.

@crip659 Nothing can change the footprint issue other than counterweights and engine hoists usually have no fit problem--they just roll under the car from the front.

The existing proposals have serious cons:

The hoist requires much more space than is implied in the answer by crip659, and it probably won't reach high enough to clear the cabinet anyway. It's also heavy and cumbersome itself.

The pulley on the ceiling proposed by Traveler requires a large anchor, itself requiring large fasteners and associated holes, and it risks cracking up drywall with such a heavy concentrated load. At best it'll require substantial ceiling repair.


You need a dunnage approach, such as is used by house movers.

Procure a lever-and-fulcrum device and some stackable blocking. This can be as simple as a 1x8 board and some scrap lumber or concrete blocks.

Position the lever under the front of the unit. Position the fulcrum block under the lever, with the lever at a reasonable angle.

Have a helper pull forward on the top rear of the unit as you lever up the front, keeping the unit level and off the walls. Slide "dunnage" under the unit to maintain the lift. A third person would be helpful here.

Set the unit on the dunnage.

Reset the lever with a taller fulcrum.

Repeat the process to lift the unit in stages, adding dunnage with each stage.



image source

I think this Jenga™ method has the best chance of working in such tight spaces, while providing for horizontal movement as required once the necessary height has been reached.

Thank you very much for your suggestion! I did some searching and couldn't find a hoist small enough that would fit into my bathroom. I will give this approach a try next. Probably going to utilize a car jack for the lifting. I hope it can push the machine high enough so that stuff can go below it.

After doing some snooping with Google based on another answer I would like to suggest a modification to your approach:  In looking up air jacks I find there are also air wedges--same general idea but in a much smaller form factor.  Your lever approach is going to be hard, use a couple of air wedges to do your lifting and then your solution.

Good grief. It's not made of lead. Just use a simple lever.

With a simple DIY and a $20 investment
you can install a system that you can use in the future for any washing machine repair access
It is called a Pulley system
It will allow to lift the washing machine with 1/8 of its weight (about 20 Pounds of its 160 pounds)
You need to install a hook in the ceiling in one of the 2x4 beams. When not used just unhook it out of the way

found on hook
if you need help how to install the hook, ask new question for details

The pulley will let you lift/lower the washing machine. But you also have to swing it out of the corner and put it down to work on it. The engine lift (the other answer) lets you do that. A fixed pulley doesn't.

Although you only need to apply 1/8th force to the rope, it's worth pointing out the obvious that the shackles (and the ceiling mounts will still be taking the full weight.

@manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact the type of engine hoist posted by crip659 requires you to be able to get the legs underneath.  Space here looks limited for that.  Personally, I'd think it'd be overkill, but this kind of engine hoist would work: https://www.harborfreight.com/440-lb-electric-hoist-with-remote-control-60346.html

This much concentrated load on a ceiling joist is risky at best. You conveniently avoid explaining how to do that safely and without huge holes.

@manassehkatz-moving-2-codidact, once it's in the air, they can slide the small cabinet and stool (that they used to put the washer there in the first place) back under it.

@isherwood I was assuming a track would be fastened to the ceiling joists, since the machine will need to come out.  I mean, I guess you could swing it from a point on the ceiling, but it'd be easier to install a track and slide the hoist along the track.
